# I have written django tests something like this. Is this the correct test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testcase

I have written django tests something like this. Is this the correct test?

```
class DaterManagerTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('ali','ali@gmail.com', '123456')

    def test_dater_profile_manager_active(self):
        """
        Make sure that DaterProfile active method works.
        """
        DaterProfile.objects.create(user=self.user) #Created object
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            DaterProfile.objects.active(),
            map(repr, DaterProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)), ordered=False
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests should be as simple (dumb) as possible and always examine one and only one thing. So i suggest to break your test into simpler steps. One test for examining your manager, another for repr, and another for testing that order is false. Sounds dumb, but think that when one test fails, you know exactly where and what is the problem.